# Need help debugging python html generator

Tags: python, pywin32

The program is supposed to take user input, turn it into html and pass it into the clipboard.

Start the program with welcome_msg()

If you enter 1 in the main menu, it takes you through building an anchor tag. You'll add the link text, the url, then the title. After you enter the title, I get the following errors:

```
File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
  welcome_msg()
File "C:\Python26\html_hax.py", line 24, in welcome_msg
  anchor()
File "C:\Python26\html_hax.py", line 71, in anchor
  copy_to_clipboard(anchor_output)
File "C:\Python26\html_hax.py", line 45, in copy_to_clipboard
  wc.SetClipboardData(win32con.CF_TEXT, msg)
error: (0, 'SetClipboardData', 'No error message is available')
```

Here's the Code:
http://pastie.org/398163

What is causing the errors above?

Comment: Give us some more detail - what's wrong with it? What should happen, and what does happen?

Comment: When you run it: welcome_msg(), it brings up the main menu, you enter 1 to construct an anchor tag that links to somewhere, 2 just makes ordered or unordered lists for now so ignore that.. 3 is an img tag builder, you enter img src, alt and it should output an image tag. Everything goes to clipboard

Comment: If you go through #1, everything works fine until you add the title attribute, then it gives you errors. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I mean actual results when you try to run the program: what happens that tells you it's not working? What error messages do you get? Copy-and-paste is good... Also, edit the question to include this info rather than putting it in comments.

Comment: Still new here, thanks for the help with forming/formatting the question, everyone.

Comment: @Dancrew32: Please Provide Code here.  Code somewhere else is a pain in the neck to search through.

Comment: @S.Lott, I will do so in the future. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `make_link` function you construct a `link_output`, but you don't actually return it as the functions result. Use `return` to do this:

```
def make_link(in_link):
  ...
  if title == '':
    link_output = ...
  else:
    link_output = ...
  return link_output
```

This way you get the value passed to your `anchor_output` variable here:

```
anchor_output = make_link(anchor_text)
```

This was `None` because the function didn't return any value, and setting the clipboard to `None` failed. With the function returning a real string it should work as expected.

Comment: It seems my other functions are returning None as well, is there any way to make it not return anything visible?

Comment: At the moment you're using print to explicitly output the results of the functions, which happen to be None. If you don't want that output, simply remove these print statements...